# How do I fix this lvalue warning?

Tags: c++, arrays

My code is:

```
void main() {
 person student[10];
 
 student[0].names[0] = 'C';
 student[0].names[1] = 'a';
 student[0].names[2] = 'm';
 student[0].names[3] = 'i';
 student[0].ages = 16;
 student[0].sex[0] = 'F';
 student[0].sex[1] = 'e';
 student[0].sex[2] = 'm';
 student[0].sex[3] = 'a';
 student[0].sex[4] = 'l';
 student[0].sex[5] = 'e';
 student[0].month = 8;
 student[0].day = 2;
 student[0].year = 1993;
}
```

All of the "student" is underlined saying expression must be a modifiable lvalue. How can i fix this?

#### `person`

```
typedef struct person 
{ 
char names[20][10]; 
char sex[6][10]; 
int ages[10]; 
int month[10]; 
int day[10]; 
int year[10]; 
} person;
```

Comment: Could you show us the definition of `person`?

Comment: Also, please look at strcat(), sprintf() and friends.

Comment: typedef struct person {
 char names[20][10];
 char sex[6][10];
 int ages[10];
 int month[10];
 int day[10];
 int year[10];
} person;

Comment: Tangential, but it'll help you use the stored values later to store `\0` at student[0].names[4] and student[0].sex[6], unless you initialized names and sex to be filled with all `\0`

Comment: typedef struct person {...} person - looks strange. Try typedef struct _person {...} person

Comment: @Alex Or, if this is really C++ and not C, just leave off the typedef entirely and write `struct person { ... }`

Comment: I think this is C, and the op doesnt know it.

Comment: @Itsik: I hope so.  Otherwise, just use `std::strings`.

Comment: @Itsik The question was originally tagged `visual-c++`, so I suspect that this is someone trying to learn C++ who hasn't quite figured out the ++ part yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Array usage

You say you have:

```
typedef struct person {
    char names[20][10];
    char sex[6][10];
    int ages[10];
    int month[10];
    int day[10];
    int year[10];
} person;
```

There's no need for the `[10]`'s. You already have that in the `person student[10]` declaration, which is the proper place for the `[10]`. Remove the extraneous arrays:

```
typedef struct person {
    char name[20];
    char sex[6];
    int age;
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} person;
```

### String handling

Also your strings aren't **null-terminated**. In C strings need to have an extra `'\0'` character at the end to indicate where the end of the string is. Your name assignment, for example, should be:

```
student[0].name[0] = 'C';
student[0].name[1] = 'a';
student[0].name[2] = 'm';
student[0].name[3] = 'i';
student[0].name[4] = '\0';
```

Actually though, there's an easier way to assign to a string than to do it a character at a time. The **strcpy** function will copy an entire string in one go:

```
strcpy(student[0].name, "Cami");
```

Or, the easiest option of all is to use the **string class** available in C++. It makes string-handling a whole lot easier than the C way of manipulating character arrays. With the string class your code would look like this:

```
// Modified struct declaration.
typedef struct person {
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    int         age;
    // ...
} person;

// Modified assignment.
student[0].name = "Cami";
```

Comment: A person might have more than one name. (First, middle, last, after marriage...). Sex on the other hand ...

Comment: But if you are using more than one name, you would have to store the names like `student[0].names[2][0] = 'C';` and not how Sarah has it in the code.

Comment: Also, the question is marked `c++`.  `std::string` is probably the way to go in this instance.

Comment: @Sarah If you found this answer the most helpful, you should "accept" it by clicking the checkmark to its left.

Answer (score 2):

Why have you defined `names` as a 2D array with `10` columns? Do you think you need to do this because you are going to create 10 objects of `person`?

If that's the case, remember this: when you create the `person` structure, you just have to define member variables for that **one object**.

So if your `person` only has one name, and one sex (which needs 6 characters to define) just use that many because when you create 10 objects of person (`person student[10];`) you are creating 10 unique copies of the `person` object! So `person[0].name` is different from `person[1].name`.

So let's first define member variables in `person` for **one** person:

```
struct person 
{ 
char names[20]; 
char sex[6]; 
int age; 
int month; 
int day; 
int year; 
};
```

And then assign characters to the name as you've detailed in your code.

Now, this is **not** a great idea because `names` is uninitialized. So `student[0].names[4]` is undefined (when it should a null character to terminate it). Have you considered using `std::string`? You have C++ after all!

Also, you'll notice I've changed the definition of `person` ('struct person ... `instead of`typedef .. `) since this is all you need to do in C++.

#### Changes:

Consider the following `person` structure:

```
#include <string>
struct person 
{ 
    std::string person;
    std::string sex;
    int age; 
    int month; 
    int day; 
    int year; 
};
```

Now, you can assign a string by just:

```
person student[10];
student[0].name = "Cami";
student[0].sex = "Female";
student[0].age = 16;
student[0].month = 8;
student[0].day = 2;
student[0].year = 1993;
```

And suppose you want to populate it with a `for` loop with keyboard input --- it's much easier now:

```
#include <iostream>
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
 std::cin>>student[i].name;
 std::cin>>student[i].sex;
 std::cin>>student[i].age;
 std::cin>>student[i].month; 
 std::cin>>student[i].day; 
 std::cin>>student[i].year; 
}
```

Comment: Yep.. array of struct, which is exactly what he needs

Answer (score 2):

`student[0].names[0]` has a type of `(char *)` and cannot be assigned to.

You need to assign to `student[0].names[0][0]` (or change the definition of `names`)

Answer (score 1):

A non-modifiable `lvalue` is addressable, but not assignable.

Having said that, are you intending for the `struct` to be a container for a bunch of different names?

What you really need is an array of `struct` to create a container for persons. (i.e. `struct person p[10];`)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need those extra `[10]`s on each of the fields of the `person` struct. This makes those fields into arrays themselves. You want, for example, an array of ten persons, each of which has an age. What you have right now is an array of ten persons, each of which has ten ages.

Each element of the `student` array has its own instance of each of the fields defined in `person`, so the fields do not themselves have to be arrays.

Answer (score 0):

1. If `person` isn't defined in this file, your are probably not including the proper header file.
2. Don't forget to add `\0` to your strings
3. If names is a 2d array, shouldnt it be :

   names[0][0] = 'J';
   names[0][1] = 'i';
   names[0][2] = 'm';
   names[0][3] = '\0';

Comment: im brand new to all of this and have no clue what i am doing, so i thought that the second [] said how many names there are. is that why its messing up?

Comment: Names in general, or for a specific person ?
Each instance of person has all the fields of the struct person. If you want a person to have a single name as a string, you should define char name[20]. If you want, for instance, the first middle and last name to be in different strings, you should define char name[3][20]